# is there a more graceful way to save sparkSQL dataframe/dataset to mysql other than simple jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, scala, apache-spark

I'm new to the bigdata erea. I'm trying to read some json files and do some parsing and then save to mysql. But all the egs. I found was df.jdbc(xxx). I was using mybatis, hibernate, jpa to do the saving part before, so I wonder if there is a more graceful way to do so.

Comment: You only can access by jdbc

Comment: *JPA* implementations are higher level APIs using *JDBC* under the hood, and *JDBC* source from *Spark SQL* is also the higher level API using  *JDBC*  under the hood. You should not be worried that you would need to handle connections etc. manually as in plain *JDBC*, because *Spark SQL* would do that for you.

Comment: So we do not need to consider atomic or transaction something like that? For me it feels weird.

Comment: @masqueradeSolitude Not really, *Spark SQL* doesn't expose it to you. You could probably write your own format that could allow you handling *JDBC* directly.